# Вывести дату в datagridview

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте) у меня вот что. Я на с# подключила БД, выполняю запросы БД в с# и у меня есть такой запрос, который бы по заданной дате выводил список нужных мне данных, но он выдает ошибку о неправильной конвертации данных в дату.не знаю как быть.Пробовала по-разному. Пожалуйста,хелп) вот код:

```
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename=D:бла-бла");
DataSet data_set = new DataSet();
string zapros1 = string.Empty;
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("textBox1.Text", "yyyy-M-dd", null);
zapros1 = @"select * from Data1(" + d + ")";
MessageBox.Show(zapros1);
SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(zapros1, conn1);
data_adapter.Fill(data_set);
dataGridView1.DataSource = data_set.Tables[0];
```

Comment: А что за ошибка? Преобразование строки в дату, или запись даты в базу данных?

Comment: Вы уверены в правильности вашего запроса? Что такое Data1?

Comment: Да-да)Data1 это функция (запрос)в моей БД) я уже разобралась)спасибо) сделала безо всяких конвертаций)вот:

            DataSet data_set = new DataSet();
            string zapros1 = string.Empty;
            zapros1 = "select * from Data1('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
            MessageBox.Show(zapros1);
            SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(zapros1, conn1);
            data_adapter.Fill(data_set);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data_set.Tables[0];

И все работает)нужно было просто одинарные кавычки мне изначально добавить и не мучаться с этими конвертациями)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте:

Параметры в запросах: [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@DateStart", 
    SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.IsNullable = true;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Для конвертации даты используйте [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Так же есть наглядный пример в MSDN, как использовать SqlDataAdapter с [параметрическими запросами](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо большое) но у меня что-то не получается совсем((